# Why Oracle says 'SET TRANSACTION' is one means of transaction beginning

Tags: oracle, transactions

In Oracle document http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/transact.htm#CNCPT88952, it says:

> A transaction begins when the first executable SQL statement is
>   encountered. An executable SQL statement is a SQL statement that
>   generates calls to a database instance, including DML and DDL
>   statements and the SET TRANSACTION statement.
>   When a transaction begins, Oracle Database assigns the transaction to
>   an available undo data segment to record the undo entries for the new
>   transaction.

My understandings of the preceding statements are,

1. SET TRANSACTION is one way to beginning a transaction;
2. a mile stone of the transaction beginning is **available undo data segment** is assigned;
3. **transaction id** is part of **available undo data segment**, therefore will be assigned after running the SET TRANSACTION.

But my following test doesn't satisfy my theory,

```
SQL> -- I suppose there's no other session is using this database
SQL> show rel;
release 1102000200
SQL> set transaction name 't1';
Transaction set.
SQL> SELECT XID, XIDUSN, XIDSLOT, STATUS from v$transaction;
no rows selected
```

It surprise me that there's no rows in transaction view. What's wrong with my hypothesis?

Answer (score 3):

You skipped the last, most important sentence from the quoted text:

> A transaction begins when the first executable SQL statement is encountered. An executable SQL statement is a SQL statement that generates calls to a database instance, including DML and DDL statements and the SET TRANSACTION statement.
>
> When a transaction begins, Oracle Database assigns the transaction to an available undo data segment to record the undo entries for the new transaction. **A transaction ID is not allocated until** an undo segment and transaction table slot are allocated, **which occurs during the first DML statement.** A transaction ID is unique to a transaction and represents the undo segment number, slot, and sequence number.

`SET TRANSACTION`  is not a `DML (Data Manipulation Language)`, it is a `transaction control statement`, see this link for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_1001.htm

You need to run **DML statement** in order to see the transaction is V$Transactions view.

**======= EDIT - SET TRANSACTION syntax (parameters) =============== 


[image]**

See this link for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF01705

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! That means the SET TRANSACTION do start a transaction even it doesn't allocate a transaction id. So does SAVEPOINT. Right?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't start the transaction. It is kind of "configuration" statement only - it sets parameters of the next transaction, but does not start it yet.

Comment: I believe these two will start the transaction conceptually even they don't cause any physical changes (transaction id hasn't be allocated). Let me take an example to explain my state. Suppose we only focus on one table and two sessions; 1. session 1, first run " set transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE;", then run select * against the table. 2. session 2 meanwhile update the table and commit the changes. 3. after session 2's commit, session 1 run the same query as step1, it'll return the same result with step1. In my session 1, I do get a logical transaction even there's no DML.

Comment: You said the transaction control statement is "'configuration' statement only", can you elaborate on what kind of parameters they will set?

Comment: I've appended the syntax of `SET TRANSACTION` to the answer - you can set the following parameters using this command: a name of the transaction, an isolation level, a read/write mode, a rollback segment.